# Python basics Calculator in streamlit

Tags: python, streamlit

im pretty new to python and i have an assigment to create a calculator in streamlit in python, and im having trouble with making it happen, im in a course where the teachers are extremely un-helpful and its bothering me so much that i need to learn by myself, i tried to start the code of the calculator and i reached a breaking-point where i can't continue it, simply because i dont know how, i need to pass a string of math problem (1+1, 5*8, etc..) and the calculator will print "your answer is:" and the answer, can u please help modifying the code and explain what u did? Thanks in advance.

```
 import streamlit as st

st.title(' ofir Calculator')
strex=""
st.text_input('Please enter a mathematical expression',strex)

def valid_expression(strex):
    for i in range(len(strex)):
        if (strex[i]>='0' and strex[i]<='9') or strex[i]=='+' or strex[i]=='-' or strex[i]=='*' or strex[i]=='/':
            if i==0:
                if strex[i]=='+' or strex[i]=='-' or strex[i]=='*' or strex[i]=='/':
                    return False
            pass
        else:
            return False

if not valid_expression(strex):
    st.error("Invalid Exrpession")
```

Comment: this web page can give you hints : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/a-beginners-guide-to-streamlit/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a revised code from your code. I added some characters to be legal and we use eval() to calculate the value of the expression. Code is commented.

###### Code

```
import streamlit as st


def get_value(user_expr):
    """
    We use eval() to get the value of the expression.
    ref: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval
    """
    return eval(user_expr, {"__builtins__": None})


def valid_expression(strex):
    """
    Evaluate if strex is a valid mathematical expression.
    """
    for i in range(len(strex)):
        # If the first char is invalid.
        if i==0:
            if strex[i] in ['+', '-', '*', '/', '%', ')']:
                return False

        # If the last char is also invalid.
        if i == len(strex) - 1:
            if strex[i] in ['+', '-', '*', '/', '%', '(']:
                return False

        # Validate char if it is a number, operators or parenthesis.
        if (strex[i] >= '0' and strex[i] <= '9') or strex[i] in ['+', '-', '*', '/', '%', '(', ')']:
            continue  # continue with the next character
        else:
            return False
    
    return True  # We cannot find invalid chars.

    
def main():
    st.title(' ofir Calculator')

    # The input value from the user will be saved in user_expr.
    user_expr = st.text_input('Please enter a mathematical expression')

    if not valid_expression(user_expr):
        st.error("Invalid Expression")
    else:
        st.success("Valid Expression")

        # Get the value of the expression.
        value = get_value(user_expr)
        st.write(f'The answer is {value}.')  # ref.: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html


# Entry point
main()
```

###### Sample Outputs

[image]

[image]